# Trying to create an embed able Vue Component bundled with Laravel Mix

Tags: vue.js, laravel-mix

I have created a SPA dashboard using Vue.JS and Laravel, and now would like to create a script that I can use in other sites I manage to just display the event data I am creating in the dashboard via the APIs I have made. I am using Laravel's webpack.mix to do my bundling. Thus far, I haven't really found anything for this situation that explains what I need to do. Any pointers would be helpful, and I can post my code, if I knew what code would be helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't entirely understand what you want to do but maybe this project will help.  It's a Vue Component bundled using Laravel Mix and deployed to npm: https://github.com/niiknow/vue-datatables-net